# Cannot infer a return type for Action delegate when used as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have the following method in VB.NET:

```
Private Sub DelegateTest(ByVal doSomething As Action(Of TrimEntry))
    doSomething(New TrimEntry())
End Sub
```

The following attempt to call the method results in a compile time error *Cannot infer a return type. Consider adding an 'As' clause to specify the return type.*. (I've left out some of the code for brevity, but my call requires more than a single line statement.)

```
DelegateTest(Function(item)
                 item.Length = 0
             End Function)
```

Perhaps I'm spoiled by C#, but it's pretty straightforward in C#.

```
DelegateTest(item => { item.Length = 0; })
```

**Question**:
*Why* is this error occurring? I'm confused, since the type is an Action delegate, which returns void. Why would I get an error on the return type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your anonymous method has no return value you need to use `Sub` instead of `Function`.